# Get query of the table with all the records in it in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI I have a table in SQL. I want to create that table into another machine and get the DATA inside that table as well.

I don't wanna use the backup method because I have existing Stored Procedures in the other machine. I just want to get one table with all the records in it. ANy idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a linked server on the target database and query the source database from the target?